# codeigniter - Get desired array from function which result is a list of array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

So I have this function `getList`. What I'm trying to accomplish is:

1. get function `stateApi` which result is an array list.(this function is an API.)
2. get only the desired array from the array list.
3. save to database.

The result of the `stateApi` function is:

```
Array
(
[ack] => Array
    (
        [ackstatus] => OK
        [ackreason] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[type] => 01
[states] => Array
    (
        [statecount] => 3
        [state] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [cd] => 01
                                [name] => America
                                [desc] => USA
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [cd] => 02
                                [name] => China
                                [desc] => CHN
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [cd] => 03
                                [name] => Russia
                                [kana] => RSA
                            )

                    )

            )
    )
)
```

What I only want to get are the contents of `state` array.
this for example:

```
[0] => Array
(
     [@attributes] => Array
     (
          [cd] => 01
          [name] => America
          [desc] => USA
     )
 )
[1] => Array
(
     [@attributes] => Array
     (
          [cd] => 02
          [name] => China
          [desc] => CHN
     )
 )
[2] => Array
(
     [@attributes] => Array
     (
          [cd] => 03
          [name] => Russia
          [kana] => RSA
     )
 )
```

here's my code so far as I could do;

```
//TODO:
//call api
$prefapi = $this->itpApi->getPrefectures();

foreach ($prefapi as $pref) {
    $data = $pref["states"]["state"];
}
//Save DB
$this->db->insert('Prefecture',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all the state array in one row you can get that without foreach like below:-

```
 $prefapi['states']['state'];
```

or if you want one by one you can do this

```
 foreach($prefapi['states']['state'] as $value)
    {
       then your insert query
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by add the one array variable.

```
$insertData = array(); 
$prefapi = $this->itpApi->getPrefectures();

foreach ($prefapi as $pref) {
    $insertData[] = $pref["states"]["state"];
}

$this->db->insert('Prefecture',$insertData);
```